# Angular - *ngFor not showing data

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-template

I am following the angular.io tutorial on creating a single paged application.
From my understanding`<[tag] *ngFor="let [localVariableName] of [arrayName]">`
You should then be able to use localVariableName to access the type's member variables.
It's a bit long so I've posted it in to Pastebin. 
http://pastebin.com/UHewKHH4
I have already gone through the tutorial once but I am going through for the second time trying to customize it to my own needs.

Cheers.

Comment: Add code as text, not as screenshot

Comment: You really think ngfor is in angular?, can you show us example?

Comment: @Jigar7521 Yes it is angular2

Comment: Ohh then please mention it in tag, there are not mentioned angular 2 in this

Comment: Please Show an small runable example

Comment: @Jigar7521 have added this tag

Comment: If you remove the CSS that is not relevant to the question the code isn't long anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `localVariable` name is only available within `<[tag]>...</[tag]>` and not in the whole template.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/cG8kTaWTwMohqfFTS6cy?p=preview)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! For some reason in the tutorial of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html, using the example of

Comment: Accidentally hit enter too early. 
 
Excellent, thanks! For some reason in the [tutorial(]angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html), the example describes the code
`<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">`  as
`The let keyword before "hero" identifies hero as a template input variable. We can reference this variable within the template to access a hero’s properties.`

Comment: Could be a bit more specific. Would you mind creating a bug report in http://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues ?

Comment: Done and dusted. Cheers mate